# Remove tick from checkbox if confirm prompt false

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using this HTML:

```
<tr>
  <td class="smalltext" width="100%">
     <label>
       <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="guarantee" id="guarantee_check_tick" />
       &mdash; Tick this checkbox if you are going to give 100% satisfaction guarantee.
     </label>
  </td>
</tr>
```

and jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    $("#guarantee_check_tick").click(function()
    {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.is(":checked"))
        {
            confirm('Are you sure you are going to provide 100% satisfaction guarantee?');
        }
    });
});
```

Now what it does, when a user clicks on the checkbox, a confirms shows (which is fine) and the checkbox is ticked when user clicks "OK" button, if a user clicks on "Cancel" button (on confirm prompt) then the checkbox should remain un-ticked. How can I achieve this?

Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`confirm` method returns boolean. Check whether it is true or false and perform execution.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#guarantee_check_tick").change(function() // changed from click to change
    {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.is(":checked"))
        {
            if(confirm('Are you sure you are going to provide 100% satisfaction guarantee?') == true){
                //your code
            }
            else{
                $this.removeAttr("checked");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/B86Sp/)

Comment: Thanks Hiral, this is perfect! I'm accepting your answer in 5 minutes because the system here is not allowing me to accept atm.

Thank You so much for your time.

Answer (score 3):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/88LHL/

Doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.confirm

This will fit your need `:)`

**Code**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#guarantee_check_tick").click(function () {
        var success = false;
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.is(":checked")) {
            success = confirm('Are you sure you are going to provide 100% satisfaction guarantee?');
        }


        if (success == true) {
            alert('Changed');

            // do something                  
        } else {

            alert('Not changed');
            $this.prop('checked', !$this.prop('checked'));
            // Cancel the change event and keep the selected element
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this,

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($)
    {
        $("#guarantee_check_tick").click(function()
        {
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.is(":checked"))
            {
                var r = confirm('Are you sure you are going to provide 100% satisfaction guarantee?');
                     // r value is either true or false

                if(!r){
                    $this.attr('checked', false);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you Chinnu R, you too.